# Simple probability question. Silver and roman coin

Tags: probability

An archaeologist has discovered a small cache of 20 ancient coins. He notes that 12 of the coins are Roman and 8 are Greek. He also notes that 6 of the Roman coins and 3 of the Greek coins are silver. The remaining coins are bronze. What’s the probability of selecting a silver or Roman coin from the cache?

Solution from book:
$$P(silver \space or \space roman ) =P(silver) +P(roman)-P(silver \space and \space roman )$$
$$P(silver \space or \space roman ) =\frac{9}{20} +\frac{12}{20} -\frac{6}{20} =0.75$$

Why I can't use the product rule here $P(silver \space and \space roman )$? The answer then becomes
$$P(silver \space or \space roman ) =\frac{9}{20} +\frac{12}{20} - \frac{9}{20}*\frac{12}{20}  =0.78$$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Because "silver" and "roman" are not independent properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299231/simple-probability-question-silver-and-roman-coin/4299284#comment8953413_4299231), "silver" and "roman" are not independent.
Here is a small schema to explain how the probability is calculated and why "silver" and "roman" are not independent.

[image]